# autenticação de login com pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com um problema que sempre cai independente na linha de erro Incorrect Password, esse script estava em mysqli e estou tentando passar para PDO. O que pode estar errado?

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();

if ( !isset($_POST['usuario'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}

if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,password FROM users WHERE usuario = ?')) {
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['usuario']]);
    $result=$stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {

        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['usuario'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['usuario'] . '!';
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username!';
}
die();
```

Comment: Em qual momento você esta fazendo a atribuição do $password que vem do banco de dados?